# strtotime не работает php

Tags: php, mysql

Друзья, есть дата 2300-01-01 00:00:00

`strtotime('2300-01-01 00:00:00')` ничего не выдает. вопрос почему?? в некоторых местах на сайте пользовался этим же кодом и все работает..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из описания функции `strtotime`

> Корректным диапазоном временных меток обычно являются даты с 13 декабря 1901 20:45:54 UTC **по 19 января 2038 03:14:07 UTC**. (Эти даты соответствуют минимальному и максимальному значению 32-битового знакового целого).
>
> Кроме того, до PHP 5.1.0, не все платформы поддерживают отрицательные метки времени, поэтому поддерживаемый диапазон дат может быть ограничен Эпохой Unix. Это означает, что даты ранее 1 января 1970 г. не будут работать в Windows, некоторых дистрибутивах Linux и нескольких других операционных системах.
>
> **В 64-битных версиях PHP** корректный **диапазон временных меток фактически бесконечен**, так как 64 битов хватит для представления приблизительно 293 миллиарда лет в обоих направлениях.

Comment: спасибо! это правильный ответ

Answer (score 1):

Функция strtotime принимает строку. Вот так должно работать `strtotime('2300-01-01 00:00:00')`

Comment: @iSeeDev Благодарность можно выразить пометив ответ, как правильный)

Comment: strtotime($data_card['active']) - вот в этом случае выдется пустота. если вывести отдельно $data_card['active'] то мы получим 2300-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: Может ошибка из-за слишком большого года? если так то почему?

Comment: @iSeeDev попробуйте еще так: strtotime(strval($data_card['active']))
Если не заработает, приведите весь код, в т.ч откуда берется переменная $data_card

Comment: Кажется дело не в этом. какой то бред. вообщем В базе данных данное поле active имеет DATETIME. ТОлько что я изменил значение на 2016-01-01 00:00:00 - и в этом случае вывело корректное strtotime, как только я меняю год на 2100 - выдает пустоту.. почему так?